# get iphone orientation in background mode

Tags: iphone, background, orientation

I need get the device orientation(portrait, upsidedown, landscapeleft, landscaperight) after the app enter background and then send it to another device through Bluetooth. [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation not working in background mode. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a private method called `-[UIApplication _getSpringBoardOrientation]` which just calls another private method `-[UIApplication activeInterfaceOrientation]`, which seems to give you the orientation of the current foreground app.

But as of my knowledge I do not think that it will capture orientation changes in background because **UIDevice** class not work like that. But you can do capture the last state of orientation when your application enters in the background using

```
Objective-C
    -(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 

Swift
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication)
```

Comment: yes, I tried this method. This way can get the foreground app orientation, but if no app(only screen) is in foreground, how can I get the device orientation?